# Convergence of bounded sequence. Limit superior

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Bertsekas' book on non linear programming says $y_m = sup \{x_k | k >= m\}$ has a limit whenever the sequence $ {x_k}$ is bounded above. His reasoning is that this sequence is always monotonically non-increasing.

Consider the sequence $x_k = 2-k$. Its bounded above but not bounded below.  And $y_m =  sup \{x_k | k >= m\} = x_m$. So this sequence does not converge even though its bounded above

Is bertsekas wrong or have I misunderstood something

Comment: You also need that $x_k$ is bounded below; perhaps this is tacitly understood (for instance, if $x_k$ is known to be non-negative)?

Comment: I don't know much about Bertsekas or non linear programming, but are you sure it isn't specified that $x_n \ge 0$ (it may be even implicit regarding of context)? As such, it seems to me that your counter-exemple is right.

Comment: Being bounded doesn't necessarily imply convergence. Your example is a good demonstration of this. Convergence implies boundedness, but not the other way around.

Comment: On a second read, you say: "His reasoning is that this sequence is always monotonically non-increasing." This is true ($\forall m \in \mathbb N, y_{m+1} \le y_m$). But you need $x_n$ to be bounded below to prove convergence.